# Constructing a regex pattern using result from an awk function

Tags: awk

I am constructing a regex pattern using the result `digt_rl` obtained from calling the function `dgrul`.

Firstly I have to remove the enclosing brackets `[...]` from `digt_rl` and store the result in `dgt`.  Then I have to construct the regex expressiion in `rl` using the `dgt` value.  How can I do this?

```
digt_rl = dgrul()
dgt = digt_rl  # remove enclosing [...]
rl = "^[-+]?[dgt]*[.,]?[dgt]+([eE][-+]?[dgt]+)?$"
```

`digt_rl` is returning `[[:digit:]]`, I want to remove the first enclosing square brackets to get`[:digit:]`, which is then introduced into `rl` at the places showing `dgt`.

The result would be

```
rl = "^[-+]?[[:digit:]]*[.,]?[[:digit:]]+([eE][-+]?[[:digit:]]+)?$"
```

Comment: `rl = "^[-+]?" digt_rl "*[.,]?" digt_rl "+([eE][-+]?" digt_rl "+)?$"` ?

Comment: `gsub(/\[dgt\]/,digt_rl,r1)` ?

Comment: I like the gsub idea.

Comment: Have also done a ternary expression  `rl = globrl == 1 ? "?(+)*([" dgt "])?([.,])+([" dgt "])" : "^\+?[" dgt "]*[.,]?[" dgt "]+$"` with the `: ...` part on the next line.  Awk is complaining about it.  Giving me `^ unexpected newline or end of string`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for gawk is

```
rl = gensub(/\[(.+)\]/, "^[-+]?[\\1]*[.,]?[\\1]+([eE][-+]?[\\1]+)?$", 1 , dgrul())
```

If you are using the original version of the AWK, then instead of the function `gensub`, you need to use the function `sub`. However, in this case, you will have to use a variable instead of a function call as the argument parameter.

More information about string functions is here:
https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html